# BI Publisher burst results returns "No data available"

Tags: bi-publisher

When I run a Version 11 BI Publisher report that has a report and burst script that uses 2 database links the output after submitting the report returns "No data available". The output format of the report requested is Excel (xslx).

Below are the results found in the bipublisher.log file on our Windows Server. Need help to determine why we are not receiving output.

[2019-08-02T11:23:52.932-05:00] [bi_server1] [WARNING] [] [oracle.xdo] [tid: 23] [userId: ] [ecid: 617a7b4a2b313a71:-7f2f4396:16bede5b1b0:-8000-0000000000314602,0] [APP: bipublisher#11.1.1] Context: 0, code: U9KP7Q94, message: Path not found (/users/dclay/Case Management/Reports/Case Status Report 7 TEST.xdo/_report.xdo)

[2019-08-02T11:23:52.932-05:00] [bi_server1] [WARNING] [] [oracle.xdo] [tid: 23] [userId: ] [ecid: 617a7b4a2b313a71:-7f2f4396:16bede5b1b0:-8000-0000000000314602,0] [APP: bipublisher#11.1.1] Context: 1, code: U9KP7Q94, message: Path not found (/users/dclay/Case Management/Reports/Case Status Report 7 TEST.xdo)

[2019-08-02T11:23:52.932-05:00] [bi_server1] [WARNING] [] [oracle.xdo] [tid: 23] [userId: ] [ecid: 617a7b4a2b313a71:-7f2f4396:16bede5b1b0:-8000-0000000000314602,0] [APP: bipublisher#11.1.1] User (dclay) with session id: bulm672onqi9vtjcld9804jbq8hk8gio2rji12q is looking for object in biee path: /users/dclay/Case Management/Reports/Case Status Report 7 TEST.xdo/_report.xdo[[

Object Error [Context: 1, code: U9KP7Q94, message: Path not found (/users/dclay/Case Management/Reports/Case Status Report 7 TEST.xdo)]

Object found [path: /users/dclay/Case Management/Reports, type: 0]

]]

The report runs without issue if we do not burst. Bursting does not cause an external error message, but it does not burst the data.

We expect to see our reports burst by center and id.

Comment: Post the BCF please

Comment: I found a solution for this issue. There was an issue with the key in the burst definition

Answer (score 0):

::NO_DATA_TO_PROCESS::

i had the same problem:
first i checked the report.  Scheduled - unclicked bursting.  It worked i got an email.

That means the queries are ok.  The bursting definition must be wrong.
I found it - it was the delivery etc dataset in the bursting page.

It had  G_1.  I had renamed G_1 to a meanful name.  In Bursting was still G_1 which took
me a long time to see.